# Java not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, 15.04, openjdk, icedtea

When i double click on a .jar file, it opens the archive manager. I have made it executable. I have tried getting Java 6,7 and 8 from the Software center.
If i right click on the file and choose to open with a different application, no Java is on the list. doing Java -jar filename.jar works fine, though i both want to be able to open things with Java normally and i also get a unrelated error if I do it that way.